# Right way to configure keymaps?

Tags: 10.10, keyboard, locale

Whats the recommended way of setting keymaps loading on Ubuntu 10.10?

I have tried `dpkg-reconfigure console-data` but it doesn't seem to work. Neither does edit of /etc/default/console-setup

`loadkeys <keymap>` works fine and I could load it myself, but where is the recommended place to store it?

I'm using a virtual appliance from bitnami so perhaps it's tweaked a little.

Comment: The BitNami virtual appliance is just Ubuntu 10.10 with the minimum software to run the BitNami servers. It is not tweaked so the default solution for Ubuntu should work. You may need to install additional packages that would be installed in a default Ubuntu desktop installation though.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)